# R Commander import Excel file

Tags: r-commander

Am using R Commander and trying to import a data set in Excel on a pc running Windows.  Commands: Data > Import Data > from Excel file.  When I do so I get the following R error message:

Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: carData
Loading required package: sandwich
Loading required package: effects
lattice theme set by effectsTheme()
See ?effectsTheme for details.
Rcmdr Version 2.5-1
Attaching package: 'Rcmdr'
The following object is masked from 'package:car':
    Confint
Error in xlsx_sheets(path) : Evaluation error: 'exdir' does not exist.

Don’t think it’s a problem with Excel file.  Have installed R Commander three times and encountered problem consistently.  Doesn’t work in csv format either.  Mystery given I have RC on another pc and am not having this problem with same Excel file.  What is the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks, RB

Comment: Could you [edit] your text and highlight the actual question?

Comment: I would suggest updating R and if it doesn't work, import data using the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the package readxl from the tidyverse to load your file.
It's tried and true and easy to use.

First install the package from CRAN by running:
`install.packages("readxl")`

Then import the library: `library(readxl)`

And finally read your excel file into an environment variable

`my_spreadsheet <- read_excel("my_excel_file.xlsx")`

This should work for both .xlsx files and .xls files

For more information see https://readxl.tidyverse.org/